# drop primary key returned error 1064 in my case

Tags: mysql, database

my table 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT9YU.jpg

my query

```
ALTER TABLE tasks DROP PRIMARY KEY task_name;
```

I got this error:

'#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'task_name' at line 1'

Answer (score 1):

Column name is not required, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tasks DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Remember, You should remove the autoincrement property before dropping the key. If you have any foreign key reference, first remove them and drop your primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE tasks DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: task_id should be the primary key, I just want to drop the PK on task_name. In my case, it seem like task_name have a PK. Look at the icon color.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your picture, it looks like task_name is column that you set up to have a foreign key relationship. If that is the case, you can't drop a FK by deleting the column. You have to instead use the name of the FK relationship you gave when you created the FK.

If you want to get rid of the task_name column you have to use the DROP COLUMN syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete column task_name which is not primary key. it can be easily drop by this query

```
ALTER TABLE tasks DROP task_name
```

Comment: I don;t want to drop the column but remove its PK

Comment: as you mention the error you are trying to drop the column task_name as primary key. so then again try to drop only primary key with the syntax given in answers by my friends. and see what happen.

Comment: how to identify a PK on a column in myphpadmin? I tried your method. Drop the column and add back. But the icon is grey in color. does that indicate it has PK? how to identify there is a PK on a column?

Comment: bro in a table there can be only one primary key in a table. ok export table structure see it.